# Why "const" is ignored in "const typename iterator_traits<RandomIterator>::reference"?

Tags: c++, reference, iterator, constants, value-type

I have the following function and vector:

```
template <class RandomIterator>  RandomIterator upperBound(RandomIterator start, RandomIterator end, const typename iterator_traits<RandomIterator>::reference t);

vector<int> v{1,2,3,3,4};
```

But it does not work when I call:

```
upperBound(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
```

The error (from g++ and clang++) is some thing like "expecting lvalue; can not passing a rvalue to the 3 argument". However, shouldn't the following two types

```
const typename iterator_traits<RandomIterator>::reference
const typename iterator_traits<RandomIterator>::value_type&
```

equivalent to compilers?

By then way, when changing the function spec to

```
template <class RandomIterator>  RandomIterator upperBound(RandomIterator start, RandomIterator end, const typename iterator_traits<RandomIterator>::value_type& t);
```

everything works fine.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I prefer putting the `const` after the type. It's clearer IMO: `typename iterator_traits<RandomIterator>::reference const` is a `T& const`, not a `T const&`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they aren't equivalent. When you have `const some_typedef`, the `const` applies to the outermost type of the typedef. So if `some_typedef` is a reference type (which in your case it is), then the `const` applies to the reference. Since there's no such thing as a `const` reference type, the `const` gets ignored.

That is, if the element type of your vector is `int`, then:

- `const typename iterator_traits<RandomIterator>::reference` becomes `int& const` which is equivalent to just `int&`.
- `const typename iterator_traits<RandomIterator>::value_type&` becomes `const int&`.

Comment: +1, One thing I tend to advice new programmers is to write the `const` in the *right* side which is, incidentally, the right of the variable.  This sort of problems just disappear, if you type `typename iterator_traits<RandomIterator>::reference const`, then it is much easier for a human to realize that this is `int& const`, and since that `const` makes no sense it get's dropped.